# Android Notification Channels. Disable Sound for group

Tags: android, notifications, notification-channel

I have channel group

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(GENERAL_CHANNEL_ID,
            GENERAL_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
    notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroup(new NotificationChannelGroup(group, groupName));
    notificationManager.notify(code, getNotificationSingle(intent, title, message, group).build());
    notificationManager.notify(groupCode, getNotificationGroup(intent, title, message, group).build());
```

I want to disable the sound of notification if there are more than 2, but I still have the sound.

```
 @TargetApi(26)
public Notification.Builder getNotificationGroup(PendingIntent intent, String title, String body, String group) {
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), GENERAL_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_qlub_logo_trans)
            .setColor(colorForOreo())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setGroup(group)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{250, 300, 800})
            .setContentIntent(intent);

}

@TargetApi(26)
public Notification.Builder getNotificationSingle(PendingIntent intent, String title, String body, String group) {
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), GENERAL_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_qlub_logo_trans)
            .setColor(colorForOreo())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setGroupAlertBehavior(Notification.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setGroup(group)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{250, 300, 800})
            .setContentIntent(intent);

}
```

Adding `Notification.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY`  doesn't help. Maybe I am trying to group them in a wrong way, but how can I disable the sound if the group has 2 and more items?

**EDIT**

Moving `.setSound()` from `Notification.Builder` to `NotificationChannel` instance and setting `setOnlyAlertOnce(true)` solved the problem.

Comment: when you make changes of sound or vibrate notification, you need to remove app cache, before you try some changes. did you do this?

Comment: @VadimEksler I don't. Why shall I?

Comment: GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY is for notification groups, not channel groups